# What are the advantages and disadvantages of grids vs. snoots for light control?

Tags: lighting, lighting-modifiers, grid

Both are, in general, used to control the area that's lit.

What are the relative advantages and disadvantages of both? When would you prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general snoots give more gradual falloff than grids. Grids are effectively a collection of very tight snoots next to each other, as a result they spill much less light at the end and give you a more direct narrower beam. They are used when you really need to control the light to highlight an object/detail and restrict it to a specific area.

In addition to differences in the quality of light, shoots are much easier to manufacture in an emergency from objects you happen to have to hand!

Comment: You beat me by a button-click. The only thing I had to add was that a grid can be **huge** (covering the entire surface of a jumbo softbox) and still be very directional. Somehow, that doesn't seem to warrant a whole different answer...

Comment: Stan: Actually I think it does, esp. if you add in that huge = soft.

Comment: Hmm, this answer and [this one](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8858/grids-vs-snoots/8860#8860) seem in direct conflict with each other. Could we get more information on the fall-off characteristics of each?

Comment: Huge doesn't necessarily equate to soft. The light may strike a large area, but it can also be very directional, since the light from each of the little snoots that make up the grid can have a very tight beam spread (as little as 5 degrees). A gridded softbox can have very even coverage (low fall-off) over a large area, but still have nearly the shadows you'd expect from a spotlight since each illuminated spot on the subject is recieving light from only a very few cells in the grid. (Mind you, the light from a reflector placed opposite the box would be very soft.)

Comment: @Stan, look at all the rep you're missing out on. :-P

Comment: Believe it or not, I'm not in it for the rep. I just want other people to have the same kind of fun (which comes from not having to think too much about the tools) as I used to have taking pictures. (I say "used to have" because I've got to wait a bit to get some kit modified to work with my disabilities -- I've got a lot more to work with lately in this digital era, so I think it's time to get back into the game.) I can do everything except mod stuff with the rep I have now, so why go fishing?

Comment: @lindes It depends somewhat on the relative lengths of the mods, I'll try and draw a diagram explaining what's going on, but in the meantime here's a good writeup of what the mods do:  http://blog.nikonians.org/martin_joergensen/2008/07/flash-modifiers.html

Comment: @Stan Rogers - (I actually started writing this comment disagreeing with your 2nd comment here, but then I had a thought (I saw the light...) - an example to demonstrate your point). In the extreme case, think of a "huge" light source comprised of an array of thousands of aligned lasers. This will be like a softbox with infinitesimally dense and long grid. When lighting a subject with this kind of light, it is easy to understand why, even though the source is very big in area, you see very sharp shadows.

Answer (score 6):

A snoot would have stronger edges on the shadow, but then it depends on the size of the grid also.

You can check this [comparison of different light sources](http://www.bron.ch/visatec/tutorials/light-comparison/) and [this nice setup](http://www.pbase.com/haverstick/image/97338725).

Comment: +1 - very cool links.  I never cease to be amazed at how much lighting stuff there is to play with.